# mongoengine query projection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I want projection in mongoengine raw query , here is my query but it don't works

```
query  =  {'$or':[{'col1':{'$regex':srch_text}},{'col2':{'$regex':srch_text}},{'col3':{'$regex':srch_text}}]}

projection = {'col4':0}
test= Test.objects(__raw__=(query,projection))
```

p.s : without projection it works

```
test= Test.objects(__raw__=(query))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__raw__` doesn't take a projection, so you should combine with [only](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.only) eg:

```
tests = Test.objects(__raw__=(query)).only('col4')
```